# do FullScreen Activity in android when press button

Tags: android, android-activity, fullscreen, android-fullscreen

I have an activity that I want when press an option in menu to make this activity as full screen and when press other option in menu back to normal activity. 
how to do this in code considering that I stopped the landScape layout

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hmm before being fullscreen is it a dialog ?

Comment: I edited my question to be clear

Comment: by Default you can show a dialog Fragment and when full screen button is pressed open it in activity, finish the activity and you will be  back to dialog fragment when he again selects the option from MENU, and for transition btw activities/dialogs you can add custom Animation.. Long shot but worth a try .. your choice

Answer (score 2):

> I have an activity that I want when press an option in menu to make
>   this activity as full screen and when press other option in menu back
>   to normal activity. how to do this in code considering that I stopped
>   the landScape layout

I think your goal is not possible because it can be done only and also it has to be called in `onCreate()` method like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
   getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

or via `XML`

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the window class from the Android API  -

requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do it just by calling `recreate()` (level 11, if I recall) on your `Activity`. Whether that's a good idea, is another thing altogether.